# how to prove that after specific value of negative power, any two exponential functions will be equal?

Tags: limits, exponentiation

I need to show that for any two functions $1-e^{-(a+b)}$ and $1-e^{-(a+c)}$ they are approximately equal after a certain limit of $a, 1000000 for example,$, given that the $ b,c \ge 0$ . **Is it possible to make approximate proof?** 
means to show that after some value of 'a', the two exponential functions are approximately equal. And any addition to the power for example value 'b' will not play important role in a function. For example here, if a=1000000 the value of the second expression will be very closed to zero.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. I guess that you want to write $1-e^{-(a+b)}$ instead of $1-e^-(a+b)$, right? Anyway it is not clear what means "they are equal after cretin limit of a"

Comment: @Masacroso *certain (probably)

Comment: @user_194421 it is still not clear, what means "they are equal after certain limit of a"?

Comment: Is it possible to make approximate proof? means to show that after some value of 'a', the two exponential functions are approximately equal. And any addition to the power for example value 'b' will not play important role in a function. For example here, if a=1000000 the value of the second expression will be very closed to zero.

Comment: @ahmadi the function $f(x):=e^{-x}$, when $x$ goes to infinity, goes to zero. Without lose of generality we can assume that $c> b>0$, then exists some $\gamma>0$ such that $c=b+\gamma$, thus $$1-e^{-(x+b)}-(1-e^{-(x+c)})=e^{-(x+b+\gamma)}-e^{-(x+b)}=e^{-(x+b)}(e^{-\gamma}-1)$$ where $e^{-\gamma}-1$ is a constant and $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-(x+b)}=0$, so the difference between the functions becomes arbitrarily small for $x$ arbitrarily big.

Comment: @ Masacroso, thank you very much.